# PHP - Variable names as Array Keys

Tags: php, arrays, variables, key

I'm looking for something like the opposite of extract().

Say I have a few variables

```
$state = "FL";
$city = "Hollywood";
$zip = "33021";
```

How can I make an array that uses the variables' names as the array keys:

```
array( "state"=>"FL", "city"=>"Hollywood", "zip"=>"33021" );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [`compact()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function though. Such as:

```
$state = "FL";
$city = "Hollywood";
$zip = "33021";
$array = compact('state', 'city', 'zip');
```

Edit: Seems to do exactly what you need, don't know why you don't think you need it. If you're looking for something *exactly* opposite of `extract()`, such as taking all available variables and putting them into an array, you can't do that, because PHP would literally take *all* variables in the current scope and put them into the array. You have to specify which variables somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure if your correct or not.. but you do realize he said explicitly in the question that its NOT `compact()` right?

Comment: compact() has a downside, in that most IDEs won't realize there is a hidden reference to those variables.

Comment: Yeah, `compact()` is the answer  but please avoid it to avoid confusion.